# Model boolean method doesn't work properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Entry with boolean column `published`, which is set to `false` by default. Here's the complete migration file:

```
class CreateMultifloraEntries < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :multiflora_entries do |t|
      t.string :type, index: true
      t.string :title
      t.string :slug, unique: true
      t.json :payload
      t.integer :user_id, index: true
      t.boolean :published, default: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

In my `models/entry.rb` I added the following method:

```
def published?
  Entry.where("published", true)
end
```

and in `index.html.erb` I've got this:

```
<% @entries.each do |entry| %>
   # ...
   <% if entry.published? %>
     <p> Published <p>
   <% else %>
     <!-- There will be an AJAX request to set entry published later -->
     <%= link_to "Publish", "whatever-path" %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, when I create an entry and navigate to my index view, the entry is shown as published.

Comment: Your `self.published?` method alway return true.

Comment: I get it and I edited my question - I made a mistake in it, instead of `self.published?` I've got just `published?` method. How could I rewrite it?

Comment: It still alway return `true`. No need a method in the model for this, the answer below is right.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I explained why :(

Comment: You doing something wrong.

Comment: @Зелёный Have no idea what exactly :( I'll extend my question with a migration file

Comment: as per above code snippet remove `def published?
  Entry.where("published", true)
end` from your model `entry`, it will works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, for any boolean attribute, rails gives you a helper method by default. You don't need to define it. So, in your case `entry.published?` will work without your own written method. Remove your own method definition it is not needed.

Just to FYI one more thing is, you defined a class method, not an instance method. Like the method you wrote, is callable like `Entry.published?`, but not on the instance of `Entry`. But in this case `entry.published?` will work because Rails defined it for you out of the box, because `publish` is a boolean field. Now, you have to fix your class implementation of the method as:

```
def self.published?
  self.where(published: true).any?
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of your suggestions have worked :(
For the first - it was my error, I have `published?` method instead of `self.published?` (edited my question).
I tried to remove the method completely and tried your variant - it returned me a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 It must have to work, u need to give probably correct method name. Add the code you tried and you got the error. What is the actual field you added to the model.

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 You will never use `self.published?`, that will create class method, which is not what you want in this case. But the instance method Rails will define for you. Let me know the actual field name and code that throws error. Paste the error in the question.

Comment: I've extended my question with the migration file, look it up. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexNikolaev94 open your rails console, and try the same and see if you get the same error? [ref link](https://makandracards.com/makandra/607-automagical-methods-for-boolean-attributes-in-activerecord)

Comment: Well.. open your rails console and do `Entry.new.methods.grep(/publis/)` and tell me what you see

Comment: I removed that method from my model and ran yours, here's [what I get](http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2016/08/511b5577fd48a845ea58d8980c454102.jpg). `Entry` is a model from my CMS plugin, and `Post` inherits from it (STI).